# Safari 15 - Display Favicons In Favorites Bar

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Is there a way to replace the favorite titles with the site's favicon in Safari 15?
I have found a handful of programs claiming to do this, but they are all for older versions of Safari.

The ones I tried are:

- FaviconBar https://github.com/RoryCombe/FaviconBar
- Faviconographter https://timingapp.com/faviconographer/

They both failed as they are designed for older versions of Safari.